# JavaScript function is firing only when you click "Delete" link in second row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a jquery datatable in view, now i want to implement delete functionality. but the problem is javascript function is only fired when i click on the "delete" link in the second row, in other rows javascript function is not getting fired.

```
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="tblDetails">
        <thead style="background-color:#ee5e45; color:white">
            <tr>
                <th>Movie Name</th>
                <th>Release Date</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Movies as List<Movie>)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.ReleaseDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Genre)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Price)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.code }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" }) | 
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.code }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash", id = "dlt" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

And the java script code is given below

```
@section Scripts {
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert//lib/sweet-alert.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#tblDetails').dataTable();
    });

    $("#dlt").click(function (e) {
        //whenever our button is clicked

        e.preventDefault();
        //get a reference to the container form 

        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then(function () {
            //user selected "Yes", Let's submit the form
            _form.submit();
        });

    });

</script>
    }
```

Please Help me in this regard thanks in advance.

Comment: `id` should be unique in entire html document. All of your delete buttons are having the same `id`. Try changing it to a class.

Comment: abhishekkannojia is right. if you search for a id jquery gives back 1 element (the last that can be found in the document) and not an array of elements. Try to set the id to index of the element in your Movie array and set the class to Delete. after that you can work with ``$(".Delete").each((count, element) => { ... });``

Comment: @mtizziani, Its actually the first element with that `id`, not the last

Comment: Thanks Alot, I have used class name instead of id its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have multiple rows so can't use id attribute for multiple rows. in this case you can use class attribute

```
<td>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.code }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" }) | 

@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.code }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash deleteRow" })
</td>
```

in script just change the selector

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#tblDetails').dataTable();
    });

    $(".deleteRow").click(function (e) {
        //whenever our button is clicked

        e.preventDefault();
        //get a reference to the container form 

        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then(function () {
            //user selected "Yes", Let's submit the form
            _form.submit();
        });

    });

</script>
```